# Ошибка зацикливания редиректа на поддомене

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, slim

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой ошибкой: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.`
Использую Slim Framework для роутинга. Ошибка возникает при попытке перехода на несуществующий адрес. На локальном сервере всё хорошо работает: сервер выдает говорит, что страница не существует и Slim показывает 404 страницу. А вот на хостинге уже другая ситуация. При попытке перейти на следующую страницу сервер возвращает мне 500 ошибку с текстом, который написан выше. Не могу понять в чём может быть проблема. Точнее, есть подозрение, что в `.htaccess`, но не понимаю, что там может быть не так.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Может `index.php` нет на месте?

Comment: Нет, он лежит в корне как раз, вместе с .htaccess

Comment: Добавьте флаг `R` и посмотрите в браузере куда идет редирект. Еще у браузера кеш можно почистить для сброса редиректа запомненного.

Comment: @Visman куда нужно добавить этот флажок?

Comment: @Visman `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L,R]` так?

Comment: Да, чтобы в браузере видно было путь в строке запроса.

Comment: @Visman сделал, очень странный результат получается. Редирект идёт вот сюда: http://a.b.ru/var/www/user/data/www/a.b.ru/index.php (где a.b.ru - поддомен.домен.ru)

Comment: А если вместо `index.php` поставить `/index.php`?

Comment: @Visman да, это решает проблему с 500 ошибкой, но происходит сразу редирект на index.php, вместо 404 ошибки, почти помогло :(

Comment: Флаг `R` уберите, теперь он не нужен.

Comment: @Visman да, всё отлично работает теперь! Забыл убрать его! Спасибо большое за помощь. Можете отправить ответ, я помечу как верный!